# Need explanation for "+(x > 180)" or "+()"

Tags: javascript

I found this in some javascript code: `+(x > 180)`

the return of this seems to be 0, for x smaller than 180, and 1 for x > than 180.

Its a smooth way for a simple comparison, but i cant find any documentation for this comparison and im not sure where it comes from (javascript/jquery/other library). So im not sure when i can use it.

i mean, i know what x > 180 is, but how does a simple "+()" around it, replace a whole "if(x >180){return 1;} else {return 0}.

Can someone plz give me an explanation or a link to a ducumentation for this statement. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the return of this seems to be 0, for x smaller than 180, and 1 for x > than 180.

Right, because `+(x > 180)` is two expressions:

- `x > 180` - This will evaluate either `true` or `false`
- `+(true or false)` - The unary `+` operator will coerce its operand to a number. `true` coerces to `1`, and `false` coerces to `0`. (This is defined by [§11.4.6 - *Unary `+` Operator*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6) and [§9.3 - *ToNumber*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3) in the spec.)

So you end up with `1` if `x` is greater than `180`, or `0` if `x` is less than or equal to `180`.

Comment: Thanks, that was very extensive! :)
So if i understand this right, i can use the Unary + Operator on  true or false for 1 or 0 or on every string that is actually a digit, like var str = '20';. everything else will lead to NaN?

Comment: @rave: Pretty much. Note that if the thing you're applying `+` to is a string, not only do strs like `"10"` work, but also strs like `"0x10"` (which converts to 16 -- 0x means hex). Some engines treat leading zeros to mean octal, though they shouldn't. So when converting user input, sometimes you're better off with `parseInt(xyz, 10)` -- e.g. specify decimal (radix 10) explicitly. But `parseInt` is a pain because it will happily convert "123abc" to 123 (it ignores trailing invalid characters). Finally, the implicit coercion rules can be a bit tricky, for instance `+""` is `0`.

Answer (score 3):

`+` simply converts to a number.

For example:

```
var str = '20';   // is a string
var num = +str;   // typecasting the string to a number
console.log(num); // returns (int) 20
```

Comment: [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_%28.2B%29)

Comment: Maybe it's worth explaining the forgiving nature of JavaScript.